# C++ strcat_s String is not null terminated

Tags: c++

My code gives me an error:

Debug assertion failed.

Expression: (L"String is not null terminated" && 0)

```
class Rectangle {
private:
    char* objID;
}

Rectangle::Rectangle(const Rectangle& rect ) {
    std::cout << "Copy constructor for: " << rect.objID << std::endl; // отладочный вывод
    objID = new char[strlen(rect.objID) + strlen("(кoпия)") + 1];
    strcpy_s(objID, strlen(objID), rect.objID);
    strcat_s(objID, strlen(objID), "(копия)");
    name = new char[strlen(rect.name) + 1];
    strcpy_s(name,strlen(name), rect.name);
    A=rect.A;
    B=rect.B;
}
```

Comment: In C++, prefer `std::string` to raw character arrays.

Comment: `strlen(name)` should probably be `strlen(rect.name)`. Actually, saving the length is a better idea than calling strlen 3 times on the same string.

Comment: You can't call `strlen` on a char pointer which points to a non-terminated sequence of characters. Above, `strlen(objID)` and `strlen(name)` are wrong. Dealing with these issues is tricky, that's why we have `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like;

```
const char* psuffix = "(кoпия)";

size_t size = strlen(rect.objID) + strlen(psuffix) + 1;
objID = new char[size];
strcpy_s(objID, size, rect.objID);
strcat_s(objID, size, psuffix);

size_t size2 = strlen(rect.name) + 1;
name = new char[size2];
strcpy_s(name, size2, rect.name);
```

The second parameter of `strcpy_s`/`strcat_s` is the length of the buffer, including the space you reserved for the `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```cpp
> objID = new char[strlen(rect.objID) + strlen("(кoпия)") + 1];
> strcpy_s(objID, strlen(objID), rect.objID);
> ```

At the time of creation, `objID` contains uninitialized memory. It is filled with random data. Therefore `strlen(objID)` will not return the size allocated in the `new` operation (`strlen(rect.objID) + strlen("(copy)") + 1`), but will return the length of random data (terminated with `\0` character).

```cpp
int size=strlen(rect.objID) + strlen("(кoпия)") + 1;
objID = new char[size];
strcpy_s(objID, size, rect.objID);
```